# Не находит таблицу

Tags: mysql

При вводе данных вида `login:password`, данные должны записывать в БД, но этого не происходит, и выдается ошибка:

> Table 'xxx.vk' doesn't exist

Создал таблицу с 1 ячейкой, но ошибка не пропала.

Comment: Опишите ваш SQL запрос

Comment: Есть одностраничный сайт, при вводе данных, данные должны записываться в БД, этого не происходит, так не была найдена таблица, я создаю таблицу, ошибка не пропадает.

Comment: Покажите код, а также скрин ошыбки

Comment: Код ошибки "Table 'xxx.vk' doesn't exist" 
Код- обычная форма авторизации

Comment: А вы к базе данных подключены? Покажите способ подключения